# Difference in char datatype in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Is their any difference between `char(1)` and `char(1 byte)` in Oracle?
Example:

```
create table aaa(flag char(1));
```

and

```
create table aaa(flag char(1 byte));
```

In the first example Explicitly i did not mentioned byte or character. Hence the default value will be BYTE or CHARACTER?

Answer (score 3):

It will depend on the setting of [`NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams127.htm). As per the documentation, this defaults to `BYTE`.

Depending on this setting, there is a major difference between

```
CHAR(1 CHAR)
```

and

```
CHAR(1 BYTE)
```

The former will allow storage of 1 character, including those which require more than one byte to encode, whereas the latter only allows for 1 byte of storage and will not be able to store characters which require 2 or more bytes to encode.

As a result, it is always a good idea to explicitly qualify the size of `*CHAR` fields explicitly with either `BYTE` or `CHAR`

The following shows how the storage differs.

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable
(
  Char1 CHAR(1 CHAR),
  Char2 CHAR(1 BYTE)
);

INSERT INTO SomeTable(Char1, Char2) VALUES('A', 'A');

INSERT INTO SomeTable(Char1, Char2) VALUES('Й', 'Й'); -- Insert into Char2 fails
```